# change a specific string inside html with a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, string, replace

i know that there is similiar question like mine here, but sadly not of them seems to work, anyway this is my situation;

i have multiple specific html string that i would change with a variable

the var:

```
var modelstring="something";
```

the HTML:

```
        <div class="caratteristichedesk" style="position: relative; text-align: center;font-family: &#39;corporate_s_reg&#39;;height:200px">
            <img class="pointdesk" src="img/pointers.png">
            <div style="position:absolute;top:60px;width:200px;left:5px;">Verrai ricontattato entro 24 ore per confermare i tuoi dati.</div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:60px;width:200px;left:235px;">Il dealer ti richiamerà per confermare l’appuntamento.</div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:60px;width:250px;left:435px;">Vivi l’esperienza di guida a bordo <br>della MODELLO.</div>
        </div>
```

i was looking for a very simple way to change the "MODELLO" string with my var above, anyone have an advice? thank you

Comment: enclose MODELLO wihthin a span tag with an id: <span id="toBeReplaced">MODELLO</span> then use javascript to replace this with your var: document.getElementById('toBeReplaced').innerHTML=var;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jquery free way to do it.

```js
var modelstring = "something",
    replaceSelector = document.querySelectorAll('.toReplace'),
    replaceCount;

for(replaceCount = 0; replaceCount < replaceSelector.length; replaceCount++) {
    replaceSelector[replaceCount].innerHTML = modelstring;
}
```

```html
<div class="caratteristichedesk" style="position: relative; text-align: center;font-family: &#39;corporate_s_reg&#39;;height:200px">
    <img class="pointdesk" src="img/pointers.png">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:60px;width:200px;left:5px;">Verrai ricontattato entro 24 ore per confermare i tuoi dati.</div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:60px;width:200px;left:235px;">Il dealer ti richiamerà per confermare l’appuntamento.</div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:60px;width:250px;left:435px;">Vivi l’esperienza di guida a bordo
        <br>della <span class="toReplace">MODELLO.</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to make that,

```
var modelstring ="something";
$(document).ready ( function (){ 
    $('div').each( function() { 
        var txt = $(this).text();
       $(this).text( txt.replace("MODELLO", modelstring) );
    });  
});
```